# Intelligent auto closing matching characters

Tags: emacs

In some of the modes I'm using, emacs helps me by auto closing some elements such as quotes, parenthesis.

However some times, out of habit I type the closing element my self and end up with `())` or `"""`.

How can I set up emacs to ignore the extra key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is fun to roll your own, [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/) has emerged as **the** canonical solution to this problem.  It does everything you ask, and a few things, you didn't know you wanted.  Emacs wiki [entry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs).

Emacs 24 (currently in pretest) will be prepackaged with an electric pairing package.  Autopair is still much more sophisticated than the builtin one.

Comment: Very good. My answer came from the same wiki page you linked to, but I can't remember *when* I actually scooped the code. From a quick test, it looks like autopairs.el works just as well and offers more features at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: As a long time user of autopair.el, I can tell you that the built-in electric pairing support in Emacs 24 is hardly inferior.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing, but backspacing "(|)" here does not remove the pair, which autopair does.  Also autopair has hooks to modify pairing behaviour.  For example I have a function that pads braces with spaces for Ruby code, and there is another function that handles triple quotes for Python.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I had had the following in my .emacs for a while, and it worked fine so I didn't think too much about it. As event_jr points out in his answer, the same features (and apparently a bit more) can be had with the autopairs.el package, linked from the same page that I got this code from.

I have the following code in my `.emacs` to do this, taken from [the emacs wiki:](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs)

```
(setq skeleton-pair t)

(setq skeleton-pair-alist
      '((?\( _ ?\))
    (?[  _ ?])
    (?{  _ ?})
    (?\" _ ?\")))

(defun autopair-insert (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let (pair)
    (cond
     ((assq last-command-char skeleton-pair-alist)
      (autopair-open arg))
     (t
      (autopair-close arg)))))

(defun autopair-open (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((pair (assq last-command-char
            skeleton-pair-alist)))
    (cond
     ((and (not mark-active)
       (eq (car pair) (car (last pair)))
       (eq (car pair) (char-after)))
      (autopair-close arg))
     (t
      (skeleton-pair-insert-maybe arg)))))

(defun autopair-close (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cond
   (mark-active
    (let (pair open)
      (dolist (pair skeleton-pair-alist)
    (when (eq last-command-char (car (last pair)))
      (setq open (car pair))))
      (setq last-command-char open)
      (skeleton-pair-insert-maybe arg)))
   ((looking-at
     (concat "[ \t\n]*"
         (regexp-quote (string last-command-char))))
    (replace-match (string last-command-char))
    (indent-according-to-mode))
   (t
    (self-insert-command (prefix-numeric-value arg))
    (indent-according-to-mode))))

(defun autopair-backspace (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (eq (char-after)
      (car (last (assq (char-before) skeleton-pair-alist))))
      (and (char-after) (delete-char 1)))
  (delete-backward-char arg))

(global-set-key [backspace] 'autopair-backspace)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [backspace] 'isearch-delete-char) ;; required to fix behaviour in isearch

(global-set-key "("  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key ")"  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key "["  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key "]"  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key "{"  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key "}"  'autopair-insert)
(global-set-key "\"" 'autopair-insert)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's Emacs 24 feature only, but `electric-pair-mode` seems to do what you want.

Comment: I already tested out autopair and it works, but I'll check this as well when I'll have some free time on my hands. Thanks!